# How do I give td elements custom id's in jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using `beforeShowDay` to give certain td elements custom classes ( I want to color the days differently based on some condition ), but it would be very helpful if I could give each td an id. How should I do this?

EDIT: Some code

```
$('.selector').datepicker({

   beforeShowDay: function(date) { 
      if(someCondition) {
        return [true,"enabled_class"];
      }
      else {
        return [false,"disabled_class"];
      }
   }

});
```

The thing is, I would like to give td cells id's of something like: `dayYEAR_MONTH_DAY` but I don't have a way of associating information with them, at least I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Please provide some of your code

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS nth-child() selector to grab the td in the table and then apply the attr function